# Playing part of a sfx audio file in HTML5 using WebAudio

Tags: html5, audio, chrome

I have compiled all of my sound effects into one sequenced .ogg file. I have the start and stop times for each sound effect. How do I play the individual effects? That is, how do I play part of an audio file.

More specificially, I've created a dictionary

```
{
    'sword_hit':
    {
        src: 'sfx.ogg',
        start: 265, // ms
        length: 212 // ms
    }
}
```

that my play_sound() function can use to look up 'sword_hit' and play the correct audio file at the correct start time for the correct duration. I simply need to know how to tell the WebAudio API to start playing at start ms and only play for length ms.

Comment: Have you [googled this topic](http://bit.ly/12VBeEL) yet? There's so much docs on the web on how to do this already.

Comment: You don't understand my question. Or you didn't read it.

Comment: Have you read the actual API and found the currentTime attribute yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563887/setting-html5-audio-position

Comment: I put an answer below, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [official docs on AudioBufferSourceNode](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#AudioBufferSourceNode). You can use `start` method's `offset` and `duration` parameters to play a sound in your sequenced file by setting `offset` where a particular sound effect starts in the file and `duration` to how long the effect is.

Example:

```
var context = new AudioContext();

function playSoundEffect(start, length) { //Ex. start=265, length = 212 
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = sequencedSoundBuffer; //loaded from your sequenced.ogg file
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0, start/1000, length/1000); //Convert from ms to seconds
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry, I searched and searched for this, but couldn't find anything. Only stuff about playing whole audio files and applying filters.